# Probability of winning at least one prize in a raffle

Tags: probability, combinatorics

"A guy bought $4$ tickets in a raffle of $200$ tickets, where $5$ of them gives a prize. What the probability of the guy winning at least $1$ prize".

**My try**

After a long analysis, i think the formula for **exactly** $1$ prize is:

$$\frac{\dbinom{5}{1}\dbinom{195}{3}}{\dbinom{200}{4}}$$

But the question is about **at least** $1$ prize, and i don't know if that affects my answer.

Is my answer right for **exactly** $1$ prize?
How do i compute the answer for **at least** 1 prize?

Thanks.

Comment: Your analysis for exactly 1 prize is correct.  For at least one prize, you *could* then add this to the probability for getting exactly 2 prizes, exactly 3 prizes, and exactly 4 prizes all together.  This simplifies nicely using vandermonde's identity, but it is unnecessary since there is a much more convenient approach.  Compare the probability of getting at least 1 prize with the probability of getting zero prizes.

Comment: U mean $1-$ probability of winning **exactly** 0 prizes right?

Comment: I told you to compare them.  I didn't tell you how to compare them.  Since you bring it up, yes, they would add to equal $1$, implying that the one is equal to $1$ minus the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When solving a question asking for the probability of at least 1 event, it is a good rule of thumb to first solve the complement -- the probability of 0 events occurring -- and then subtract from 1.

In this case, we want to find the probability that, given a guy has bought 4 raffle tickets, he wins 0 prizes.

If we logically walk through this, this is equal to the event that the all the 5 prizes go to a raffle ticket other than the 4 the guy has.

The probability of a single prize going to another raffle is $\frac{196}{200}$. This implies the probability of all 5 prizes going to another raffle is $(\frac{196}{200})^5$.

So the probability of winning at least 1 prize is equal to $1 - (\frac{196}{200})^5$.

**Edit**

In the previous solution, I made the erroneous assumption that this was a raffle drawn with replacement: that is, once a ticket has been selected, it is placed back into the bin.

To solve for a raffle drawn without replacement, we have to make a slight correction to the probabilities.

The probability of the event of the first prize going away is still $\frac{196}{200}$. However, as the winning ticket is thrown away, the probability of the event of the second prize going away is now $\frac{195}{199}$. And so forth.

In total, the probability of all 5 prizes going to another raffle will be $$\frac{196 \cdot 195 \cdot 194 \cdot 193 \cdot 192}{200 \cdot 199 \cdot 198 \cdot 197 \cdot 196}.$$

The probability, then, of winning at least 1 prize is the complement:
$$1 - \frac{196 \cdot 195 \cdot 194 \cdot 193 \cdot 192}{200 \cdot 199 \cdot 198 \cdot 197 \cdot 196}.$$

Comment: I'll make a quick edit -- thanks for the correction.

Comment: Watch how many terms are being multiplied on top compared to bottom.  Your answer wound up lying outside of $[0,1]$.  Using falling factorials or binomial coefficients is an easy way to avoid the issue of needing to write out so many individual multiplicands.

Comment: Oops sorry. I tried to avoid using factorials and binomial coefficients to get a simpler intuition behind the math. Of course if a person wanted to generalize to $n$ raffles out of $k$ draws, they should be using closed form expressions.